# Throw exception from CompletableFuture thenApply

Tags: java, exception, java-stream, completable-future

Say I have the following code. I want to throw an exception from within a `thenApply` block to the parent. I want to make sure I am returning and throwing the correct values from the sub-function `doSomething` and handling it properly in the caller. Because if I write a simple unit test, I don't get the exception from `doSomething`.

A function that does the main work and returns a `CompletionStage<Result>`

```
public CompletionStage<Result> computeResult() {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b)
        .thenApply(ignore -> {
            final aValue = a.join();
            final bValue = b.join();

            doSomething()
                .thenApply(ignore ->
                    buildResult());

            return null;
        });
    
}
```

A private function that does some validations by calling another API and throws an exception or returns nothing

```
private CompletionStage<Void> doSomething() {

    if (someCondition) {
        return anotherService.shouldPerformTask()
        .thenApply(shouldPerform -> {
            // Do something
            if (someCheck) {
                throw new RuntimeException("message");  // How to make sure this exception gets returned all the up to "completableFuture.allOf"?
            }
        return null;
        });
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the function signature of buildResult

```
private Result buildResult();
```

This is how the other API call looks

```
anotherService:
CompletionStage<Boolean> shouldPerformTask()
```

I am expecting the following assertion to work. i.e. I want `computeResult` to throw a CompletionException with cause and message as `new RuntimeException("message")`

```
CompletionException e = assertThrows(CompletionException.class, 
        () -> testClass.computeResult()
            .toCompletableFuture().join());
assertTrue(e.getMessage().contains("message"));
```

Comment: You would need to call `join` on the CompletionStage returned by `doSomething`. Right now you are ignoring its result.

Comment: Thanks! Is it fine to `return null` the way I am doing in `doSomething`? Because I want to do `doSomething().toCompletableFuture().join()` and this shouldn't run into a NPE.

Comment: If `someCondition` is false, then that would throw an NPE. You could instead return a completed future to avoid that, like this: `CompletableFuture.<Void>completedFuture(null);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @marstran's suggestion, an alternate way to do this would be to use `thenCompose` to convert `Result` into `CompletationStage<Result>`.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> computeResult() {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(a, b)
        .thenCompose(ignore -> { // Use thenCompose here
            final aValue = a.join();
            final bValue = b.join();

            return doSomething()
                .thenApply(ignore ->
                    buildResult());
        });
}

private CompletionStage<Void> doSomething() {

    if (someCondition) {
        return anotherService.shouldPerformTask()
        .thenApply(shouldPerform -> {
            // Do something
            if (someCheck) {
                throw new RuntimeException("message");  
            }
        return null;
        });
    }
    return completedFuture(null);
}
```

Comment: When you don’t use `aValue` nor `bValue`, there is no need to call `a.join()` or `b.join()`.

Comment: Agree, this is a sample code. I do use the values